# making sure no requests are through GET method in the application

Tags: grails, block, http-get

in order to make sure all form submission and all data submitted to server is not through `GET` I found this piece of code

```
if(request.method == 'GET') {
      response.sendError(405)
    } else {
      // the rest of the delete action goes here
    }
```

We can apply this in out base controller which is extended by all controllers so , the code is not repeated everywhere.
The above methods checks the existing method
I want to know is there a way to set the method to `POST` throughout the application, like all forms and all data submitted should be by `POST`. any configuration/variable I use to set this ?

Thanks in Advance
Priyank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general that's what the `allowedMethods` map is for; when you use the `generate-controller` or `generate-all` script your controller will have this:

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
```

and you can add or remove action names from the map depending on which actions require POST and which allow GET. You can put this in a base class and allow subclasses to reuse the base class definition and add to it with this approach:

```
static allowedMethods = BaseController.allowedMethods + [createUser: "POST"]
```

That requires that you extend that base class, so it's easy to forget. So a better approach might be to use a filter; you can create one with the `create-filters` command.

So for example you could have a filter like this with an explicit list of actions to disallow:

```
def filters = {
   postOnly(controller:'*', action: 'save|update|delete') {
      before = {
         if (!request.post) {
            response.sendError(405)
            return false
         }
         true
      }
   }
}
```

and in addition to pipe-delimited action names (you can do the same for controller names) you can also use wildcards, so you could add in any action that starts with 'create':

```
   postOnly(controller:'*', action: 'save|update|delete|create*') {
```

Comment: Thanks Burt for the solution. Yes we are planning to move to filters from base controller, but we still have some other calls in the base controller like sanitizer plugin calls for all params in the request, etc. we wont be able to take out the baseController for now. On something unrelated issue, I wanted to know if anyone has successfully integrated the HDIV API in grails